# Computer hangs when I unplug video

Tags: linux, motherboard

I have a strange issue, one I've never seen before.  I'm trying to build a new headless computer using a mini-ITX board with a Celeron processor.  I want to put Linux on it and so far have tried Debian 7 as well as Ubuntu 14 LTS.  I get the OS installed, it reboots, I can SSH in, all is well, until I unplug the VGA or HDMI.  Then immediately the computer completely wigs out.  If I power it on with no video plugged in, the hard drive spins for a while then eventually stops, SSH isn't working, and if I THEN plug in a display, it shows a blank screen -- the monitor doesn't even come out of power save.  Same thing happens if I unplug HDMI or VGA while the computer is running, the system completely locks up.  Either way the computer eventually (after maybe 30 seconds) shuts off then powers back on and enters a reboot loop.  I have tried:

- Two DIFFERENT brand motherboards with different CPUs (both Celeron)
- Clearing the CMOS on both, eventually get the same issue
- Two different PSU's, exact same result on both
- Both voltage settings for the RAM (1.35 and 1.5)

The only two commonalities are the OS (both Debian-based, but very different kernel versions) and the RAM -- I don't have another DIMM to try.  Is it possible that it's either a Debian/Ubuntu bug or a RAM issue?  The RAM is PNY (blah I know), but if it were RAM I would not expect an issue quite like this.  The system will run stable for as long as I keep the displays plugged in.

What is up????

Answer (score 0):

Most probably is the power saving settings. You can try to tinker with the power management settings either through GUI or the example below.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower